# Short stories with musical themes

Tags: story-identification, music

I read a couple of stories in an old anthology with a musical theme. One was about a young pop star who is native American and uses ancient tribal themes in his music, unleashing forces he can't control. The other was about a time traveler who goes to the jazz age to listen to his favorite saxophonist record the greatest solo ever played, but accidentally allows the musician to hear a recording of the solo before it's been recorded. Any help?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: How old was it? Can you narrow it down to a decade or two?

Comment: The jazz story might be "Willie's Blues" by Robert J. Tilley.